# How to position parts relative to each other in Kicad?

Tags: kicad

Is it possible to automatically position parts in Kicad, relative to each other?

I'm making a board that plugs into an Arduino Nano, and I'm finding it difficult to position the straight headers at the exact 17.76 mm span to match the space between Nano's pin rows. If necessary, I can do this manually, but is there any built-in tool where I can select two parts and tell it to space them by a specific amount along a specific axis?

Is it also possible to center a part relative to the "Edge.Cuts" layer? I'd like to center these headers, and again, using the mouse while looking at the coordinates is very tedious and error prone.

Comment: Change to imperial (inch) coordinates, and you should have no problem spacing the headers 0.7 inches apart.

Comment: Or use a custom grid.  Also pick a point and press the spacebar - this sets the "local origin" and moving the mouse from that spot shows a delta x/y in the bottom right relative from that point.

Comment: @rdtsc, Yeah, I was using the spacebar to zero-out the local origin, but it's still very difficult to use the mouse to get the position exactly right. You can set a part's absolute position via the right-click menu, but that's only in absolute coordinates. Even changing the global origin in Grid Properties doesn't change that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the "Position Relative To" command.  On a Mac, it is ⌘-R, under Linux, it is Ctrl-R.  Or, you can access it using the right-click on a part or group.

[image: Position Relative]

Once you have selected this, you can choose an object for the reference

[image: Position Relative Dialog]

You will need to be running version 5 or higher for this function.

Comment: Is the "position relative" feature only in the nightly release? I'm using 4.0.7 and I don't see that option in the right-click menu.

Comment: Yes, it's only in the nighties for now (see end of my answer. :). But the nighties are pretty stable and really the way to go, feature-wise for now

Comment: I'm using Version: 5.0.0-rc2-dev-unknown-73b9a5~65~ubuntu14.04.1, release build and this option appears to be broken. I can click "Position Relative To..." in the right-click menu, but nothing happens. No pop-up window like you show here.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Please report this as a bug.  It should be working as described although the window will look a bit different than it did back in August.

Comment: Done! https://bugs.launchpad.net/kicad/+bug/1778624

Answer (score 1):

In KiCad 5, on Windows, not automatically but ...

In properties set the x,y of your first pin header, e.g. 100,100.

[image]

Do alt-v, s to specify the grid origin, giving the same x,y coordinates.

[image]

The pin header footprint now looks like this.

[image]

Place the second pin header and enter it's relative x,y coordinates, e.g. 117.76,100, (or ctrl-m on the parts to *move exactly*, setting the radio button "relative to grid origin").

[image]

Ending up with the two headers aligned the correct distance apart.

[image]

In your case you'd set the edge cut as the grid origin and position the two headers relative to there.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this specific problem I made a tool that takes position and rotation of parts and exports them as a group with the specified relative placement. You can then place the parts like a footprint without having to make one. https://github.com/snhobbs/kicad-parts-placer.